# Electron-Forge doesn't implement appDirectrory attribute in squirrel maker when installed (Windows)

Tags: electron-forge

There is a small .js app and embedded in electron-forge and it works fine, as does the building process via nmp run make.
I want the installed files to be in *C:/Program Files (x86)/app-name* , while everything I've tried leads to the app being installed in *C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\app-name* (seemingly as a default).

I have read the docu of forge: (
[https://www.electronforge.io/config/makers/squirrel.windows](https://stackoverflow.com)
[https://js.electronforge.io/modules/_electron_forge_maker_squirrel.html](https://stackoverflow.com)
[https://js.electronforge.io/interfaces/_electron_forge_maker_squirrel.InternalOptions.Options.html#outputDirectory](https://stackoverflow.com)
)

From the last link especially, I understand that *appDirectory* is the attribute I need to change in forge.config.js makers like this:

```
makers: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel',
      config: {
        
        setupIcon: './icons/33524_ICON_app-name_256x256.ico',
        icon: './icons/33524_ICON_app-name_256x256.ico',
        appDirectory: "C:/Program Files (x86)/app-name",
        //outputDirectory: "C:/Program Files (x86)/app-name"
      },
    },
```

, but it doesn't change anything. *outputDirectory*, which should define the folder of the build path, didn't change the default location either.

How can I fix this?